# Flutter: Can't get File from ChangeNotifier

Tags: image, flutter, provider, imagepicker, flutter-change-notifier

I am trying to learn provider in flutter. But I am facing a problem. I want to get `File _image` from **ChangeNotifier** But it's showing me error.

Here is ChangeNotifierProvider

```
class ImagePicker extends ChangeNotifier {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage({ImageSource source}) async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    } else {
      print('No image selected.');
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image]

and here is HomeScreen where I want to get that _image file.

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hello"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("Select a image"),
            Image.file(Provider.of<ImagePicker>(context)._image),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
                onPressed: () {
                  Provider.of<ImagePicker>(context).getImage();
                })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

**It's showing me** - *The getter '_image' isn't defined for the type 'ImagePicker'.
Try importing the library that defines '_image', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '_image'.*

Please some help me for fix this error. And explain what's happening.

Comment: _image means this variable is private. you can't use it outside.

Comment: How can I use this from outside ?

Comment: just remove the underscore :D or define a getter that return the value of ```_image```

Comment: I added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as discussed in the comments, any variable underscore prefix means this variable is private. So you have two solutions :

1. Delete underscore from `_image` and the variable will be accessible from outside the class.
2. Define getter that return `_image` value.

Answer (score 2):

Change File _image variable to File image since _image means is a private variable.
Something like this:

```
class ImagePicker extends ChangeNotifier {
File image;
final picker = ImagePicker();
Future getImage({ImageSource source}) async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

if (pickedFile != null) {
  this.image = File(pickedFile.path);
} else {
  print('No image selected.');
}
notifyListeners();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, I solved this change _image to image.
thanks @ikerfah